# Python Poetry specify dependency on `sentry-sdk[flask]`

Tags: python, python-poetry

I'm trying to add support for Sentry to an existing Python Flask application that uses Python Poetry for dependency management.

The Sentry docs say to run this:

```bash
pip install --upgrade 'sentry-sdk[flask]
```

That works. But I want to convert that into a `pyproject.toml` dependency entry for Python Poetry. If I try just this:

```ini
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
# <snip>
sentry-sdk = "1.5.12"
```

I get a `SolverProblemError`:

> ... depends on sentry-sdk (1.5.12) which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.

If I try:

```ini
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
# <snip>
sentry-sdk[flask] = "1.5.12"
```

I get `Invalid TOML file`.

How do I convert this pip dependency to Python `pyproject.toml` format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can specify a dependency with extras:

```ini
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
sentry-sdk = {extras = ["flask"], version = "1.5.12"}
```

See the following section of the documentation: [Dependency extras](https://python-poetry.org/docs/master/dependency-specification/#dependency-extras)

You can also achieve this by running:

```
poetry add sentry-sdk[flask]==1.5.12
```

Comment: The documentation for the `pyproject.toml` is improved in the `master` branch: https://python-poetry.org/docs/master/dependency-specification/#dependency-extras. For the cli command it is described at the end of this section: https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#add